# How to calculate all pairwise difference for multiple varibles

Tags: r, comparison, pairwise

I need to calculate all pairwise difference for each of these variables (there are 100 in my dataset):

[image]

Then I want to summarize (all) the values of each of the pairwise sums and arrange them in a in a matrix.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `outer` if we need a `matrix`

```
outer(seq_along(df1), seq_along(df1), FUN =
      Vectorize(function(i, j) sum(df1[[i]] - df1[[j]], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
 [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]   0.00 47.80 56.49
[2,] -47.80  0.00  8.69
[3,] -56.49 -8.69  0.00
```

---

Or if we don't need redundant comparison, use `combn`

```
combn(df1, 2, FUN = function(x) sum(x[[1]] - x[[2]], na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
[1] 47.80 56.49  8.69
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(67.81, 65.33, 54.67, 53.2, 53.77, 52.66, 
50.77, 47.84, 46.33, 44.15), V2 = c(57.68, 56.58, 52.61, 49.74, 
49.28, 48.03, 46.15, 43.96, 42.76, 41.94), V3 = c(54.04, 54.34, 
52.36, 49.34, 48.93, 48.06, 46.21, 43.51, 42.15, 41.1)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Could we also use dist like `as.numeric(dist(df1))` but it gives many numbers!

Comment: @TarJae it calculate the distance between rows.  Perhaps `t`ranspose.  Also, the default method used is "euclidean".  But I guess the OP wanted only a difference and sum

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you from Colombia

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using `dist`. With the help of akrun we get:

```
dist(t(df1), method = "manhattan")
```

```
      V1    V2
V2 47.80      
V3 56.49  8.87
```